# Loop through folder and Copy values and Formats of first sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have been working through VBA code that copies the first worksheet in a folder to another workbook.

The code copies the data correctly but upon saving I get certain cells with errors (#Ref) this is due some of the copied cells having formula.

I would like the copied to data to retain the original formatting but to only have values. Or alternatively the cells with the 2 errors are M11 and O11 which have an index match formula, if these 2 cells values could be pasted without formula the rest of the copied data will be fine.

Any help will be appreciated.

I have tried to use PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats and .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats  but I am not sure how to amend the copy function.

```
Sub MergeMultipleWorkbooks()

    Dim Path, Filename As String

    Path = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\ProMacro\"
    Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xlsx")

    Do While Filename <> ""

        With Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True)
            .Worksheets(1).Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1) 

            .Close False
        End With

        Filename = Dir()
    Loop

    MsgBox "Files has been copied Successfull", , "MergeMultipleExcelFiles"
End Sub
```

The code copies the first sheet from the designated file in the folder, my only issue is that certain cells will have a #Ref when saving the file as the formulas having being copied.

Answer (score 0):

When the workbook is opened, copy all the contents of the sheet and paste it to the same sheet as values. It's the code you put between

> With Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True) and             .Worksheets(1).Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

Formatting is not changed and formulas are replaced by values.

It's not a very friendly solution, but nothing other comes to my mind after contemplating and trying to find out a good one.